# Cannot find 'node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.d.ts' in tsconfig file

Tags: tsconfig

After I update a package , I saw this error( meanwhile I updated my vs code ) /
I dont know how to fix this error, appreciate it if anyone helps me out in this case to handle this error

```
  File 'c:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/extensions/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.d.ts' not found.
    The file is in the program because:
    Default library for target 'es5'
```

Comment: It looks like it occurred in version `1.74.0` and it was promptly fixed in version `1.74.1` and documented [in this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/168420). **So all you have to do is just update your VS Code installation.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happened to me right after I've updated my VS Code today.
Restarting TypeScript server didn't help. So I've found the answer [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/168420).

**To 'fix' it, I had to:**

1. Install the [JavaScript and TypeScript Nightly](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.vscode-typescript-next) VS Code extension.
2. Open any TypeScript file.
3. Open command pallete (ctrl+p) and type:
   `>Typescript: Select TypeScript Version`
4. Select the VS Code version.

I hope it helps.

Comment: There are reasons why someone has selected "use project version".  This isn't an "answer".  -1

Answer (score 3):

Restarting the TS server in Visual Studio Code did the trick for me as described [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/168420#issuecomment-1342977819):

`CMD`+`SHIFT`+`P` (or `CTRL`-`SHIFT`+`P`) ->

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I just got this error. It was not due to the VS Code installation. It was due to a partial "node_modules" deletion.

In your case, this new package or its dependencies did not install properly.

Exit VS Code, remove "node_modules" folder completely and run yarn again (or npm if it is your package manager).

It will be fixed.

Comment: thanks, I just did but it was not fixed
I read same issue in github , they recommend restart TS Server, it didnt work as well

Comment: Ok. Did you removed node_modules with VS Code closed and started it after?

Comment: Actually I tried both ways 
with closed vs code and also with vs code terminal